# how to parse a public google calendar without needing to login?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, calendar, google-calendar-api

First off, this is in C# using Unity3D (free, I have no budget for the project). And honestly my skill level for C# is not great, so detailed answers please?
I'm making an app as a news feed for a guild, my only difficulty has been google calendar.
What I need is to be able to get all the events for the month, then separate them into just description and a DateTime for when it occurs, in arrays that are in the same order, so I can sort it into a handmade calendar.
So for example description[2] would be for datetime[2].
If there is an alternative calendar that will fit the circumstance better I can probably get it moved over, but I'll need instructions on how to parse it for the needed information.

Using the google's API I was not able to make it get information without requiring login first, and even after that it tries to get the user's calendar, not a specific public one.

I also tried to parse the XML version of the calendar using system.xml, which also failed and it would not recognize that it had any tags. however if I appended a tag to the start and end of it, I could get the entire thing as if it had no tags (completely useless for what I need).
Mind you I was able to use system.xml fine to parse the forums (with some help from an old how-to in a unity support forum).

I also tried using windows forums web browser thingy, and the gecko version. Unity does not like those at all and they seem to refuse to render, or maybe I'm just using them wrong, I'm not totally sure.

Comment: What is the XML version of the calendar? Can you post some code that produces the failure?

Comment: A good example calendar would be [https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic)

as for the code, I have used variations of this, how ever this is the only thing that worked, and as mentioned it decides to get ALL of the data.
[http://justpaste.it/jhkn](http://justpaste.it/jhkn)

Comment: I should also mention for that code, the "UnsafeSecurityPolicy.Instate();" runs a secondary script i have that overrides the security key requirement.

Also to be more clear, it gets all the xml data as if it had no tags.
there is an ical version, if it would be easier with with that since it may be more easily read by something like System.Text.RegularExpressions.
[https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics)

Comment: **bump**  well sort of an update, a friend of mine made a DLL for me that will parse it into Lists by parsing with System.Xml, and interpreting the output of each entry with System.Text.RegularExpressions.
it works well and its a simple call of public variables.
It also has to use this to get past unity's lack of support for google's security certs. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/249052/accessing-google-apis-in-unity.html
As it's his work I can't post the DLL or its code, but this bit of info should be helpful to anyone else with the problem.